# How to understand Gibbs distribution

Tags: probability, matlab, conditional-probability, markov-process, gibbs

I have a graph model such as
[image]

Following the [Hammersley–Clifford](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~acthomas/724/Geman.pdf) theorem describes that Markov random fields exhibit a Gibbs distribution with an energy function as follows:

$$P(x)=\frac {exp(-U(x))}{Z}$$

where $U(x)$ is the Gibbs energy and $Z$ is a normalizing constant defined as

$Z = \sum_{x∈Ω} exp^{-U(x)}$

In addition, the energy function is presented with Gibbs energy:

$U(x)=\sum_{i∈I}\sum_{j∈Ni}V_2(xi,xj)+\sum_{i∈z}V_1(xi)$

where $N_i$ is $i^{th}$ class

$V_2(xi, xj) = βc$ if $xi = xj$; and equals $−βc$ if $xi != xj$

In which, $βc$ is the $β$ parameter for type $C$ clique. $C$ denotes the set of cliques in $Ni$. And the clique potential for single-site cliques depends on the label assigned to the site

$V_1(xi) = zi$ if $xi = zi$

where $zi$ is the potential for label value of $xi$

To find potential label for $xi$, we can simply apply [kmean](http://kr.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) method. That means each pixel is associated by label `0 or 1` 
Currently, To understand Gibbs distribution, I tried to implement the Gibbs energy $U(x)$ based on above definitions. This is my steps:

1. Initial Randomly N class by Kmean clustering-> output is label for each position $i,j$ to find potential for label value of $xi$
2. Compute $V_1$ and $V_2$
3. Compute $U$

I did the first step and computed the $V_2$. However, I don't know how to compute the $V_1$. **Could you see my definition and my implementation and give me some way to do it?** To my knowledge, it fails to find $V_2$ at corner pixels of the image, secondly, I have not implemented $V_1$

Here is my implementation

```
%%Given I and N,beta
function main()
I=[19    24     6    14     4    25    19     8     5;
    2     1    11    23    10    18     1    20     5;
   21     9    23    11     1    16    10    17     2;
    1    11     4     1    13     9    20    19    17;
   17     3    24    19     5    25     1    20     5;
    9    14     3     9    12    22     3     8    14;
   13    25    21    21     9    10     3     5     8;
    9     4     6    13    13    25    14    16     5;
   19    20     3     4     8     8    21    11    15];
N=2;
beta=1;
y=I(:);
labels =kmeans(y,N);   
imgLabel=reshape(labels ,size(I));
[i j]=ind2ij(labels,2);
% Compute Gibbs energy
energy=0;
for index=1:numel(i)
  energy=energy+GibbsEnergy(imgLabel,i(index),j(index),imgLabel,beta);
end
end

function energy=GibbsEnergy(img,i,j,labels,beta)
%% 8 neighborhood system
%% img is the labeled image
energy=0; %U
V2=0;
label=labels(i,j);
%North, south, east and west neighbors
if(label==img(i-1,j)) V2=V2-beta;
else V2=V2+beta;end
if(label==img(i,j+1)) V2=V2-beta;
else V2=V2+beta;end
if(label==img(i+1,j)) V2=V2-beta;
else V2=V2+beta;end
if(label==img(i,j-1)) V2=V2-beta;
else V2=V2+beta;end
%% Diagonal pixels
if(label==img(i-1,j-1)) V2=V2-beta;
else V2=V2+beta;end
if(label==img(i-1,j+1)) V2=V2-beta;
else V2=V2+beta;end
if(label==img(i+1,j+1)) V2=V2-beta;
else V2=V2+beta;end
if(label==img(i+1,j-1)) V2=V2-beta;
else V2=V2+beta;end

%% Compute V1??

%% Total energy U
energy=V1+V2;
end 
%%  index to i and j conversion
%   ind: index
%   m: height of image
%   i, j: image coordinates

function [i j]=ind2ij(ind,m)
i=mod(ind-1,m)+1;
j=floor((ind-1)/m)+1;
end
```

Comment: No one can help me!!!

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean, but I am sure that for the corner pixels you can do zero-padding.